# Create two sections in the WinUI3 app for Windows 11

Tags: windows, xaml, visual-studio-2022, winui-3, windows-11

I'm developing a new application in WinUi3 for Windows 11 but I'm having some doubts and difficulties (I've developed UWP apps and haven't had this problem, in WinUi3 the behavior seems to be different)
I have this example:

```
<StackPanel Name="Main" Orientation="Vertical">
        <RelativePanel Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlAcrylicWindowBrush}">
            <TextBlock  Name="AAA"
                        Text="AAA"
                RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
                RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True">
        </RelativePanel>
        
        <RelativePanel Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlAltHighAcrylicWindowBrush}">
        <TextBlock  Name="BBB"
                Text="BBB"/>
    </RelativePanel>
</StackPanel>
```

I want something like that in the new Paint:
[image]

Orange zone only for a simple textblock and some buttons (settings, about, etc.) and red zone to my "work zone" of my app.

I want to make this two sections. But my code in WinUI3 dont work like I want. What is the best way to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you may want to examine NavigationView?

Comment: @Luis: Are you asking for a recommendation of what layout panel to use?

Comment: I want to create two sections in my app. Top section only with simple textblock and some buttons (settings, about, etc.) with fix size and center/bottom section with my work area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "work zone" can be expanded using `Grid`.

```xml
<Grid Name="Main" RowDefinitions="Auto,*">
    <!--  MENU BAR  -->
    <NavigationView
        Grid.Row="0"
        IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed"
        IsSettingsVisible="True"
        PaneDisplayMode="Top">
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Ficheiro" />
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Editar" />
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Ver" />
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>
    </NavigationView>
    <!--  YOUR CONTENTS  -->
    <StackPanel
        Grid.Row="1"
        BorderBrush="Red"
        BorderThickness="2">
        <TextBlock Text="CONTENT #1" />
        <TextBlock Text="CONTENT #2" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And "Ta-da!"

[image]